# Passing objects to onClick methods in document.write()

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to dynamically create js objects which can also "write" themselves into the document using `Foo.write()`. The write method is just a bunch of `document.write()` calls which pulls variables from `Foo` to populate elements. So essentially, `write()` contains the template for all `Foo`s.

This works great. However, I'm running into a problem when I want to set an `onClick` to one of the template elements (an `anchor`). The line that writes the link is:

`document.write( "<a href='javascript:" +this+ "close()'><img src='layout_img/button_close.png'  /></a> ");`

So when called, the `Foo` inserts itself and `Foo.close()` should be called on that *specific* `Foo`. But when I click the link I get a js error: `"missing ] after element list"`. In the status bar, when I hover the link, it shows `javascript:[Object object].close()` which I'm assuming is a good thing.

Why isn't this working?

Here's more of my code to help. This is how I'd like to create/write my objects:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  new Foo( 'any_id_i_want', {            
    title: "any_title",
    icon: "any_image",
    isMinimized: false,
    top: 400,
    left: 500
  }).write().setContents( "Hello <a href='http://google.com'>google</a>" );
</script>
```

`write()` uses `document.write()` to create a template and uses things like `Foo.title` to customize the object's appearance.

`setContents()` finds the written code by `document.getElementById(Foo.id)` and uses `Element.innerHTML` to fill the `Foo` with a custom message, in this case text and a link.

So I'd like to keep this method of creating the objects as it's very convenient. I just can't figure out how to use the template to make calls on the `Foo`.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using `document.write`? It is a very difficult way of doing things. Also, what is the expected output?

Comment: this is an object. you need to use it like this 
document.write( "<a href='javascript: Foo.close()'><img src='layout_img/button_close.png' /></a> ");

Comment: I added more code that might help describe what I want to accomplish. I'm going to have multiple `Foo`s on a page, and each `Foo` should be able to call `close()` when the link is clicked.

Comment: Just a note; since it appears you're looking to manage window-like element objects, it may be advantageous to consider jQuery. If your project requirements are flexible in including the framework, jQuery can simplify much of what you are, and inevitably will be, trying to achieve. I found doing so easy, especially with storing arbitrary data via `.data()`, to set state flags and content data in jQuery objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you concatenate `this` with the other strings, you will get the string representation of the object (i.e. `this.toString()`). For a complex object that is not useful at all. As you see you get the text `[Object object]` instead of anything that you can use to access the object.

If you want to be able to use the object like that, the object has to know the name of a variable that it can use to access itself.

Example:

```
// create object
var x = new Foo();
// set variable name
x.name = 'x';
```

Now you can use that property to create code that accesses the object:

```
document.write(
  '<a href="javascript:' + this.name + '.close();">' +
  '<img src="layout_img/button_close.png" />' +
  '</a>'
);
```

If you instead would create the element as an object and append to an element in the page, you could simply put `this` in a local variable and use in an anonymous function, without the need of a global variable name:

```
var e = document.createElement('a');
var t = this;
e.onclick = function(){
  t.close();
};
```

(The need ot the local variable `t` is so that you get it in a closeure for the anonymous function. When the `onclick` event runs, `this` doesn't refer to your object, but the HTML element.)

Comment: Although there were many helpful answers, I used this one. With some googling, I discovered something I never knew: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable. So I set my new `Foo` to a global with the same name as the `Foo.id` and had the `write` method print out `javascript:window. "+this.id+" .close()`

Answer (score 1):

`this` is an object. There is an implicit call to the object's `toString()` when you concatenate it to a string. This is why you're seeing `[Object object].close()`. What is the output that you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of things that are not optimal here:

1. You are converting Foo, which is an object, to a String. This calls `Foo.toString()` which returns the string `[Object object]`.
2. You are assigning an event listener via a string. You should create your link and call `addEventListener` or even `link.onclick = function() { Foo.close() }`.
3. `this` changes its value depending on context. At the time of `write()` it will be something different then when you call the onclick handler. A simple solution is to use `var that = this; that.close()`.
4. Using `document.write` is probably the worst method of adding stuff to your document. Use the DOM apis to create stuff in JavaScript.

Saying that this is how I would tackle that:

```
Foo.write = function() {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.innerHTML = "<img src='layout_img/button_close.png' />";
  var that = this;
  link.onclick = function() { that.close(); };
  document.body.appendChild(link);
}
```

In your situation it might also be a good idea to look into using a [templating library](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/).